# No custom objects 'ActiveScratchOrg', 'NamespaceRegistry', 'ScratchOrgInfo' found - deployment error message in non Prod environments

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, scratch-org

A 'view all' permission set in non Prod environments must ***not*** have references to the following objects else I'll receive a deployment error:

1. ActiveScratchOrg
2. NamespaceRegistry
3. ScratchOrgInfo

The deployment error message read like this:

```
In field: object - no CustomObject named ScratchOrgInfo found
```

However, if these objects aren't referenced during a Prod deploy, then I will get deployment error messages saying that those aforementioned objects must be referenced as they depend on the 'view all' permission.

I don't understand why this delta between Prod and non Prod environments is happening - our non Prod environments are recently refreshed. I do not have the Dev Hub enabled in Prod but don't see how that could be a cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The response I got from Salesforce support on this error was to "Remove those Permission Sets from your git project and instead rely on deploying them manually."